# How i can optimize my code in php for cycle

Tags: php

At me in a cycle a hard code which is fastened as a step to me correctly to write down the code what to leave from it.

Depending on the step, the depth of the array changes

```
for($i=0; $i < $size; $i += $step){
    //WTF ?
    if ($step == 1){
        $values = $this->metricsValues(
            $metrics,
            $metricHeaders
        );
    }

    if ($step == 2){
        $values[$d[$i]][$d[$i + 1]] = $this->metricsValues(
            $metrics,
            $metricHeaders
        );
    }

    if ($step == 3){
        $values[$d[$i]][$d[$i + 1]][$d[$i + 2]] = $this->metricsValues(
            $metrics,
            $metricHeaders
        );
    }

    if ($step == 4){
        $values[$d[$i]][$d[$i + 1]][$d[$i + 2]][$d[$i + 3]] = $this->metricsValues(
            $metrics,
            $metricHeaders
        );
    } 
}
```

Comment: you could use elseif statement or a switch statement

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you are asking. Can you rephrase it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like something like this should do:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i += $step) {

    $target = &$values;

    // max(1, $j) to suppress any action when $step == 1
    for ($j = 0; max(1, $j) < $step; $j++) {
        $target = &$target[$d[$i + $j]];
    }

    $target = $this->metricsValues(...);

}
```